# Can i upload .ipa file on itune connect from my windows

Tags: iphone, cordova, app-store-connect

I am not able to find binary upload link in my itunes connect account. I have uploaded .ipa file but status is same from last 1 week " waiting for Upload".

Please any one help me to upload my .ipa file on itunes connect from windows.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cant upload ipa file to itunes from you windows system.

After upload, was there any message about successful upload? Because once you upload the binary to iTunes, status will change to "Upload Received" and then to "Waiting for review".

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your prompt reply. I did not get message of successful upload. But yes in my In-app purchase status shows "Ready to submit" and in the main page status is " waiting for upload". I have to compulsory to buy MAC OS for publish my ipa file in istore...??

Comment: may be some mistakes has been done while uploading .. follow http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/submit-app-itunes-app-store/ steps and try again to upload your app using MAC machine... :)